# Load entity without binding it to a view

Tags: odata, sapui5

In a controller (`Detail.controller.js`) I want to access an OData-Entity that has not yet been bound to a control.

If the entry `0001` of my `BananaSet` is bound to the view, I can access the raw data via

```
this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/BananaSet('0001')");
```

but the following will return `undefined` (unless it was displayed recently).

```
this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/BananaSet('0002')");
this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/MetaDataSet('0001')");
```

Is there a way to access data or entities of an OData model, that have not yet been bound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To explicitly trigger a request to an entity you may use the read function of the oData model.

Here is the official documentation:
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#read

```js
this.getView().getModel().read("/BananaSet('001')", {
    success: function (oData) {
        // do something with the Banana data
    }
})
```