# UI5: Bind a simple property of a control to a property of an OData entity

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have an OData model which I successfully use to fill eg. a table in a SAPUI5 app:

```
<Table items="{globalSettings>/APP_GLOBAL_PREFERENCES/}">
```

etc.

The entity set `APP_GLOBAL_PREFERENCES` consists of entities each having a `KEY` and `VALUE` property, with `KEY` being the, well, key.

Now, I'm trying to bind the `text`property of a `<Text>`control to a property of a specfic instance of the entity:

```
<Text text="The base URL is '{globalSettings>/APP_GLOBAL_PREFERENCES('BASE_URL')/VALUE}'" />
```

In order for this to work, I have to create an element binding, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32584095/4433535). In my case, I do it in the lifecycle method `onBeforeRendering` of the associated controller:

```
onBeforeRendering: function () {
  this.getView().bindElement({
    path: '/APP_GLOBAL_PREFERENCES',
    model: 'globalSettings'
  });
}
```

I don't understand why this step is necessary, and I would like to avoid it.
Can anyone explain why this step is required, or does anybody have a clue how to get by without it?

Answer (score 0):

In UI5, there are 3 types of bindings:

- Aggregation bindings can be used with aggregation (for example table or list `items`). This requires an array of objects from data point of view. In this case, you have to configure a so-called template, which will be repeated for every instance of the aggregation. Here, you need to use relative binding, so you don't have include the array reference itself in the binding path.
- Element bindings are used to bind objects from the model to a control (views are also controls!). If the control has any child elements, these child elements can be bound to any property of this object using relative binding.**
- Property bindings are the elementary parts of a binding procedure; each control has more or less properties, and you can assign model values to these properties using property binding.

** This means, that in your `Text` control you have to use a relative binding, so just use `{VALUE}`. However, make sure that if `APP_GLOBAL_PREFERENCES` in your model points to an array, you have to select a specific item in your `bindElement` (for example:

`this.getView().bindElement({
    path: '/APP_GLOBAL_PREFERENCES('BASE_URL')',
    model: 'globalSettings'
  });`).

**Edit:** 
Ok, now I see your problem! Answering your question: it's not necessary.

If you use the `this.getView().bindElement(..)` property, you can use relative path in your text control (assuming that you include the selection of the proper item in this segment). My examples are based on JSONModel:

`this.getView().bindElement({
   path: '/APP_GLOBAL_PREFERENCES/0',
   model: 'globalSettings'
});`

Then you can do this in your view:
`<Text text="{globalSettings>text}" />`

If you skip the bindElement (but you've assigned the model to the view), you need to use the following path:
`<Text text="{globalSettings>/APP_GLOBAL_PREFERENCES/0/text}" />`

If you are implementing a detail view, which gets the ID of the selected item as an URL parameter, it's recommended to use the bindElement with the selection to the given parameter; then in your XML view, you can use relative binding and you don't have to care about the ID of the item.

Comment: I think my original question was a litte unclear: The `Text` control I'm talking about is **not** inside an aggregation such as the `items` of a `Table` - it's on the ´top level´ of a view. The solution I presented does work the way I intended - I was just wondering if (any why) a declarative **property binding** with an **absolute path** doesn't work unless I also create an **element binding** on a parent control. Perhaps you can elaborate on this?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, and I agree it should work the way you described - but unfortunately it doesn't with an OData model. As you can see from my original question, I'm already using for the property binding the absolute binding path you suggest (although I can't use the `/APP_GLOBAL_PREFERENCES/0/VALUE` syntax since I'm not interested in a random first element in the preferences array but the element with a specific key, so I'm using `/APP_GLOBAL_PREFERENCES('BASE_URL')/VALUE` which is the correct syntax and does work) - but only if I create the element binding beforehand.

Comment: One more piece of information: My observation that I need to create an element binding (to a parent control) or the property binding won't work isn't correct. What actually **is** required is that a read request occurs to the entity set. When I manually trigger this read request (by `model.read('/APP_GLOBAL_PREFERENCES')`), then I can use the absolute binding path as you suggested (albeit with the `('BASE_URL')`-syntax as described). This is quite disappointing and I tend to consider it a bug of the OData model. But I'm open to a different explanation.

Comment: I tested and you are right. However, I don't think it's a bug, it's just a behaviour. Property binding itselft does not make a query to the underlying OData service. So if you want to use it, you have to fetch the data first, for example with read() function. With this technique accidental data request can be avoided (as you can use several property binding in a view and it's not always clear if the data has to be fetched or not if you are using absolute binding).

Comment: thank you very much for your effort. I think we have cleared up the situation, and you are right that this is 'just a behavior'. It's even [documented behavior](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2.html) (see the Note right at the beginning). In order to demonstrate this 'behavior', which is at least surprising to me, I also created a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zulapupiti/edit?html,js,console,output).

Comment: Great, I couldn't find this documentation, but now it's proved :)